# Open Facebook Messenger Chat Head usng OpenURL

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, facebook-messenger

What I am trying to do is trying to open a ChatHead in FB-Messenger using the OpenURL method in titanium.

```
Ti.Platform.openURL("fb-messenger://user/" + {user-Id})
```

I am able to open the Messenger successfully but I am not able chat with the user, as everytime I send a message it give me an alert that says "**Send Failed You cannot perform that action**".

I am not sure what am doing wrong, is it the FB messenger permission after submitting the App for Review to the Facebook.

Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: @BobSwager : I am using a titanium module ti.facebook to implement the above functionality. I search but I don't find any URL Button option in that module. Have a look at this link : [https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook]

Comment: Create it by yourself

Answer (score 0):

The URL Button can be used to open a web page in the in-app browser. This button can be used with the Button and Generic Templates.

You must post the button to user. Your JSON should be :

```
"buttons":[
      {
        "type":"web_url",
        "url":"https://yourUrl",
        "title":"View Item",
        "webview_height_ratio": "compact"
      }
    ]
```

Facebook has its own rules.

[More about this topic.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/url-button)